# Xamarin iOS aborts on call to AudioUnit.SetEnableIO

Tags: xamarin.ios

Our Xamarin-based iOS app works fine on iPhone but crashes on iPad. The offending call is to `SetEnableIO`:

```
audioUnit = new AudioUnit.AudioUnit(component);
audioUnit.SetEnableIO(true, AudioUnitScopeType.Input, kInputBus);
```

Here is output received in the debug window:

```
2016-09-20 09:59:19.006 MyAppiOX[329:100987] critical: 
Native stacktrace:
2016-09-20 09:59:19.099 MyAppiOX[329:100987] critical:  0   MyAppiOX                          0x00000001001b97d8 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 260
2016-09-20 09:59:19.099 MyAppiOX[329:100987] critical:  1   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00000001853df348 _sigtramp + 52
2016-09-20 09:59:19.100 MyAppiOX[329:100987] critical:  2   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x0000000185319480 <redacted> + 100
2016-09-20 09:59:19.100 MyAppiOX[329:100987] critical:  3   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x00000001853194c8 system_set_sfi_window + 0
2016-09-20 09:59:19.100 MyAppiOX[329:100987] critical:  4   TCC                                 0x000000018855a560 <redacted> + 0
2016-09-20 09:59:19.100 MyAppiOX[329:100987] critical:  5   TCC                                 0x000000018855a45c <redacted> + 0
2016-09-20 09:59:19.100 MyAppiOX[329:100987] critical:  6   TCC                                 0x000000018855d52c <redacted> + 288
2016-09-20 09:59:19.100 MyAppiOX[329:100987] critical:  7   libxpc.dylib                        0x000000018542401c <redacted> + 80
2016-09-20 09:59:19.101 MyAppiOX[329:100987] critical:  8   libxpc.dylib          
          0x0000000185423f8c <redacted> + 40
2016-09-20 09:59:19.101 MyAppiOX[329:100987] critical:  9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001851d91c0 <redacted> + 16
2016-09-20 09:59:19.101 MyAppiOX[329:100987] critical:  10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001851e7ab4 <redacted> + 732
2016-09-20 09:59:19.101 MyAppiOX[329:100987] critical:  11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001851e938c <redacted> + 572
2016-09-20 09:59:19.101 MyAppiOX[329:100987] critical:  12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001851e90ec <redacted> + 124
2016-09-20 09:59:19.101 MyAppiOX[329:100987] critical:  13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001853e12c8 _pthread_wqthread + 1288
2016-09-20 09:59:19.102 MyAppiOX[329:100987] critical:  14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001853e0db4 start_wqthread + 4
2016-09-20 09:59:19.102 MyAppiOX[329:100987] critical: 
=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually
indicates a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the
native libraries used by your application.
```

Does anyone know How to get around this problem? Regards.

Environment:

```
Visual Studio 2015 with update 3
Xamarin 4.2.0.680
Xamarin.iOS 10.0.0.6
iPad is running iOS 10.0.1
```

Comment: We need more details to help you. E.g. this is not a symbolicated, nor complete, stack trace. You do not state which version(s) of iOS the devices are running, neither did you specify the exact models. Also _latest version_ won't be useful as a future reference to people reading your question.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have updated the post with exact version numbers. As for stack trace, this is all I receive in VS output window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally nailed the problem down. Apparently, Xamarin has not yet been fully tested on iOS 10. The OS has introduced some new privacy settings. If you do not define the settings that your iOS app intends to use, you will see your app crash with SIGABRT errors. The privacy settings can be defined in `Info.plist.` In our case, it was `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription.` Hope you find this useful.